# How to Move Document Set in Sharepoint 2013 on premise using CSOM

Tags: csom, migration, sharepoint-on-prem, content-and-structure, document-migration

I have a requirement to move Document Set from one Subsite to Another subsite maintaining version history , metadata and Document ID using CSOM .I went through many online articles couldn't find a useful one . Through my search i came across this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7d94f9dc-fad5-43c9-822b-61af1bf84f2d/move-document-set-inquiry?forum=sharepointdevelopment

but this one doesn't work for sharepoint onpremise , the last comment is from 2017 ,has it changed now?

Kindly, let me know if there are any alternatives of doing it.Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: On-Prem why do you need to do this by using csom? You don't have farm permissions?

Comment: No i do not have farm permission and i only want to move some document set , i have tried with "Content and Structure" but the document set .zip file does not move from drop off library, it works if i do it with individual document not with document set